# Bootstrap optimism corrected - results interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, bootstrap, calibration

I came to know about Bootstrap validation approach for data poor settings. Currently, my problem is binary classification with 977 records and 6 features. class ratio is 77:23. Model is random forest

As my dataset is small, I learnt that regular train, test split may not be a good approach and that's when I came to know about bootstrap optimism corrected approach.

I am using the code from [here](https://dpananos.github.io/posts/2021/11/blog-post-34/) to adapt to my random forest model. Thanks to @Demetri Pananos

I used, n_bootstraps = 500 and scoring metric is f1. I will update my metric to custom metric later. Now, my objective is to understand bootstrap optimism and interpreting their results.

So, I simply ran two seperate two jupyter motebooks. One with random hyperparameters of random forest and other with best hyperparameters of random forest (best params were found from regular train and validated on test split)

**execution 1 - best hyperparameters**

```
Optimism Corrected: 0.58
regular cv: 0.48
Wall time: 9min 49s
Brier score loss = 0.18061299051614899
AUC = 85
MCC = 50
```

And the calibration curve looks like below

[image]

**execution 2 - random hyperparameters**

```
Optimism Corrected: 0.65
regular cv: 0.47
Wall time: 9min 49s
Brier score loss = 0.12090
AUC = 93
MCC = 68
```

and the calibration curve looks like below

[image]

As my data is imbalanced and I want better estimates upper estimates (ex: 0.7,0.8,0.9 etc), should I go with `execution 2` though it is done using random hyperparameters? brier score loss is low for execution 2

from the calibration curve, it doesn't seem like overfitting but the difference in scores between `optimisim bootstrap and regular cv` makes me think that it is overfitting. Why is the overfitting pattern not shown in calibration curve when bootstrap optimism and cv score difference is huge? Am I interpreting the right way?

**update - best hyperparameter code**

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what is happening here.  Firstly, the optimism corrected bootstrap replays all modelling procedures as if you were to do it with fresh data.  What do you mean "random hyperparameters"?  If you're estimating optimal hyperparameters, you need to include that in each bootstrap.

Comment: You may find [this](https://randomeffect.net/post/2021/03/10/bias-corrected-calibration-curve-from-scratch/) post helpful for computing bias corrected calibration plots.

Comment: @DemetriPananos - I ran bootstrap corrected optimism twice (in 2 jupyter notebooks seperately)...One with random hyperparameters and other best hyperparameters..These best hyperparameters were found seperately from gridsearchCV (completely outside of bootstrap). Later, in bootstrap optimism, I Passed these best hyperparameters to the model

Comment: @DemetriPananos - I updated the code for your reference.

Comment: Right, my objection is with "best" hyper parameters.  How did you determine those were "best"?  You need to validate the hyper parameter selection, so you're going to need to do a sort of nested cross validation.  Sklearn should have a page on nested cross validation you can borrow from. Additionally, instead of doing the optimism corrected bootstrap, you can do 100 repeats of 10 fold CV using `RepeatedKFoldCV` which should be as good as the bootstrap according to Frank [here](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/).

Comment: If your goal is just to estimate out of sample performance for a given model as well as bias corrected calibration estimates, I can try to write you some code.  Should save you a lot of time and will keep the number of questions down to a minimum.

Comment: @DemetriPananos - Thanks for your suggestion. I validated the best hyperparameters in hold out set seperately. If you have any tutorial links or plan to write, please do share it and it will be of immense help for me to know how it is done.. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so I've identified a few problems with your approach in the comments.  The key thing to remember here is that *"the model" is really a process and not a single thing*.  Anything you do in the process of creating the model is technically part of "the model" and so it needs to be validated.  For example, you mention using "best hyperparameters" but we techincally don't know what those are.  All we really say is what hyperparameters lead to smallest loss using these data, and -- now here comes the important part -- *the "best hyperparameters" might change were we to use different data to fit a model*.  That is the concept of sampling variability in a nutshell, so you need to evaluate how sensitive your model is to that variability.

In what follows, I'm going to basically show you:

a) How to to properly validate your model in cases for which train/test splits are not ideal, and

b) How to construct optimism corrected calibration curves.

I will do this all in `sklearn`.  We'll need a model which requires some hyperparameters to be selected via cross validation.  To this end, we'll use `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` with an l2 penalty.  The approaches we will develop will generalize to other models with more parameters to select, but this is the simplest non-trivial example I could think of. For data, we will use the breast cancer data that comes with sklearn.  I will include all relevant code at the end, choosing only to expose crucial code for understanding concepts. Let's begin.

---

### "The Model" vs. A Model

Earlier, I tried to make a distinction between "The Model" and A Model.  A model is whatever is going to do the learning (e.g. Logistic regression, random forests, neural nets, whatever).  That part isn't as important as "The Model" because we need to validate "The Model" as opposed to A Model.

A handy trick for understanding what is part of "The Model" is to ask yourself the following question:

> Were I to get different training data, what parts of the prediction pipeline are subject to change?

If you're standardizing your inputs, the standardization constants (i.e. mean and variances of the predictors) is going to change, so that is part of "The Model".  If you're using a feature selection method, the features you select might change so that is part of "The Model".  Everything in "The Model" needs to be validated.

Luckily, much of that stuff can be put into `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`.  So, if I'm using logistic regression with an l2 penalty, my code might look like

```py
pipeline_components = [
    ('scaling',StandardScaler()),
    ('logistic_regression', LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', max_iter = 1_000_000))
]

a_model = Pipeline(pipeline_components)
```

Now, if I had chosen an l2 penalty (`C` in `LogisticRegression`) then I would have "The Model".  However, that parameter needs to be estimated via cross validation.  To that extent, we will use `GridSearchCrossValidation`.

```
param_grid = {'logistic_regression__C': 1/np.logspace(-2, 2, base = np.exp(1))}

the_model = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = inner_cv, scoring = brier_score, verbose=0)
```

Now we have "The Model".  Remember, `GridSearchCV` has a `.fit` method, and once it is fit we can call `.predict`.  Hence, `GridSearchCV` is really an estimator.

At this point, we can pass `the_model` to something like `sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate` in order to do the optimism corrected bootstrap.  Alternatively, Frank Harrell has mentioned that 100 repeats of 10 fold CV are about as good as bootstrapping, and that requires a bunch less code, so I will opt for that.

One thing to keep in mind:  There are two levels of cross validation here.  There is the inner fold (meant to choose the optimal hyperparameters) and the outer fold (the 100 repeats of 10 fold, or the optimism corrected bootstrap).  Keep track of the inner fold, because we'll need that later.

---

### Calibration, Such an Aggravation

Now we have "The Model".  We are capable of estimating the performance of "The Model" for a given metric via this nested cross validation structure (be it bootstrapped or otherwise).  Now onto calibration via the optimism corrected bootstrap.  Much of this is really similar to my blog post.  A calibration curve is in essence an estimate, so we just do the optimsim corrected bootstrap for the calibration curve.  Let me demonstrate.

First, we need to fit "The model" and obtain probability estimates.  This will give us the "apparent calibration" (or apparent performance as I call it in my blog post).  I'm going to pre-specify some probability values to evaluate the calibration curve at.  We'll use a lowess smoother to estimate the calibration curve

```
prange = np.linspace(0, 1, 25)

# Fit our model on all the data
best_model = gscv.fit(X, y).best_estimator_

# Estimate the risks from the best model
predicted_p = best_model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]

# Compute the apparent calibration
apparent_cal = lowess(y, predicted_p, it=0, xvals=prange)
```

We might get something that looks like

[image]

Now, all we need to do is bootstrap this entire process

```
nsim = 500
optimism = np.zeros((nsim, prange.size))

for i in tqdm(range(nsim)):
    # Bootstrap the original dataset
    Xb, yb = resample(X, y)
    
    # Fit the model, including the hyperparameter selection, on the bootstrapped data
    fit = gscv.fit(Xb, yb).best_estimator_
    
    # Get the risk estimates from the model fit on the bootstrapped predictions
    predicted_risk_bs = fit.predict_proba(Xb)[:, 1]
    
    # Fit a calibration curve to the predicted risk on bootstrapped data
    smooth_p_bs = lowess(yb, predicted_risk_bs, it=0, xvals=prange)
    
    # Apply the bootstrap model on the original data
    predicted_risk_orig = fit.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
    
    # Fit a calibration curve on the original data using predictions from bootstrapped model
    smooth_p_bs_orig = lowess(y, predicted_risk_orig, it=0, xvals=prange)
    
    
    optimism[i] = smooth_p_bs - smooth_p_bs_orig


bias_corrected_cal = apparent_cal - optimism.mean(0)
```

Although I write a little class for sake of ease in my blog post, the steps presented here are nearly identical.  The only difference is that the estimate is not a single number, its a function (namely the calibration curve).  The result would look like

[image]

Note there is not much difference between the two curves. I anticipate this is due to the data *and* the fact we've explicitly traded off bias for variance by using a penalty.

---

### The Code (I know you skipped here, don't lie).

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Dpananos/852dbd0b48d2c23da2183539180d7716)

Comment: I sincerely thank you for the detailed answer and support. upvoted.

Comment: btw are you on any portals like `fiverr` or `hire the author` etc?

Comment: @TheGreat Nope.  It's all free, friend.

Comment: In regular calibration tutorials, I see that we have two options. one is platt and isotonic. Considering our breast cancer data distribution, you have chosen lowess smoothing technique here? Am I right?

Comment: Platt and Isotonic methods are for *recalibrating* the model based on data not yet seen.  The methodology presented here is for assessing the model's calibration as it stands.  The lowess smoother is a non-parametric way to estimate the calibration curve.

Comment: For how to calibrate your model with Isotonic, Platt, and histograms, this is a good resource: https://github.com/ethen8181/machine-learning/blob/master/model_selection/prob_calibration/prob_calibration.ipynb