# Statistical comparison of two probabilistic classifiers

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, classification, out-of-sample, train-test-split

**TL;DR** There are well-known tests to compare classifiers. How can we generalize to classifiers with random training steps?

---

I am comparing two classification algorithms (A and B). I can see that typically algorithm A is better than algorithm B in terms of the out-of-sample error (error meaning misclassification rate). I would like to test whether the difference is statistically significant -- A strictly better than B with a some significance level.

I found [good answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/45918/206540) on this at Cross Validated SE. However, my setting is different in the following sense: these classifiers have **random** components in the training stage, and running them on the same training set several times would result in different results.

What I have for a given dataset is the following:

- For a given train/test split of this dataset, I have 1,000 out-of-sample errors for each method (A and B), with "out-of-sample error" meaning training these methods on the training set (this includes the random component) and then testing the classifiers' errors on the test set.
- I have the above results for 100 random train/test set splits of this dataset.

What would be the best way to test significance in this setting? Thank you for your time!

---

**EDIT:** "probabilistic classifier" looks misleading. I meant, classifiers with random training components -- e.g., a decision tree where the variable to split is taken randomly out of top-x important features).

---

**Thoughts:** A naive approach is the following:

- Fix a train/test split.
- Compare 1,000 errors and statistically test A < B.
- Return the largest significance level where we fail to reject A < B.
  If we then iterate the above approach for all 100 train/test splits, we will then get 100 significance levels. I can then plot a histogram of these levels. Or, is there instead a way to uniformly compare all the $100 \times 1,000$ errors?

Another approach would instead be checking if the expected error of algorithm A is smaller than the expected error of algorithm B. I can take the average of the 1,000 errors for a fixed split, and then compare these averaged errors over 100 train:test splits via the methods in the literature.

Comment: Why are you thinking about comparing two procedures for training a classifier rather than two trained classifiers? Even if you can show that one procedure is better "on average", what we would care about in practice is the performance of a model trained with the procedure.

Comment: @dipetkov I’m not convinced of that. Read, for instance, any of the many times [Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/4253/frank-harrell) has written about bootstrapping the entire modeling procedure.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, I've read Prof. Harrell's writings on this topic. As reference to others here are some links: [1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/), [2](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/md/reg.html#internal-vs--external-model-validation). I remain convinced that when one deploys a classifier it's a particular instantiation of a training procedure, not the template for training a classifier.

Comment: Thank you both for the commens! @Dave ,dipetkov. I think, if I thought about comparing once-trained classifiers, then the link I shared above would have been sufficient. But in reality, there exist many algorithms that learn with random components. To some extent, I need to average the multiple simulated performances. Otherwise, if, for example, in a paper I say method A beats method B, but I trained just once, it would look very suspicious, as the randomness can be easily manipulated. Hence I am looking for a more thorough approach. The most convenient one seems my last paragraph in the post.

Comment: You might find this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/570269/237901) about  optimism corrected bootstrap interesting.

Comment: @dipetkov thank you!